# R function to compare csv files and list what changed between rows with same column name

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to write a function in r that takes two fairly large csv files with the same number of columns and the same column names, and compares the rows. But I am having difficulty comparing the rows, because I'd like for the function to return which column the data is changing in. For example, my dataframe/csv may be:

csv1:

```
qty    name    description                 price
2     alpha    number of alpha to order    20
3     beta     number of beta to order     30
1     gamma    number of gamma to order    10
2     delta    number of delta to order    5
```

csv2:

```
qty    name    description                 price
3     alpha    number of alpha to order    20
3     beta     number of beta pieces       30
1     gamma    number of gamma to order    40
2     delta    number of delta to order    5
1     epsilon  number of epsilon to order  10
```

and I want the function to populate a table/other dataframe that has what changed from csv1 to csv2:

```
qty    name    description                 price    change
3     alpha    number of alpha to order    20       qty
3     beta     number of beta pieces       30       description
1     gamma    number of gamma to order    40       price
1     epsilon  number of epsilon to order  10       added
```

since alpha increased in quantity, beta's description changes, and gammas price changed, I'd like those to be listed, ignoring delta where nothing changed, and showing that epsilon is a newly added row, unique from the first csv. Is this possible in r? Thank you in advance!

My current code compares the two dataframes and outputs 3 csv files. one where all the columns matched between the dataframes, a second with unique rows to the first dataframe, and a third with only unique rows to the second dataframe. So I will be comparing the second two dataframes, since the first has already sorted out where all the columns are identical.

Comment: Are you comparing row by row and if so, would the datasets be of the. same size

Comment: I think row by row would be the most logical solution, and no the dataframes may not be the same size in length. There may still be some rows where more than one column changed, or it is an entirely new row, in which case the change column would say "qty, description" if it found more than one change.

Comment: if it is not the same number of rows, then you may need crossjoin and then compare.  sorry, not clear to me

Comment: Try `i1 <- df1 != df2;names(df1)[max.col(i1, 'first') * NA^(rowSums(i1) == 0)]#[1] "qty"         "description" "price"       NA` (based on the example showed)

Answer (score 1):

if comparing rowwise, then we could do:

```
a <- which(df1!=df2,T)
data.frame(row = a[,1],change=names(df1)[a[,2]])

row      change
1   1         qty
2   2 description
3   3       price
```

EDIT:

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by = "name",all = T)
df3$row <- 1:nrow(df3)
df_from <- df3[2:4]
df_to <- df3[5:7]

a <- which(df_from!=df_to,T)
nw <- data.frame(row = a[,1],change=names(df1)[a[,2]])
added <- cbind(row = which(is.na(df_from[,1])),change = "added")
#removed <- data.frame(row = which(is.na(df_to[,1])),change = "removed")
merge(df3,rbind(nw,added)) # rbind(nw,added,removed)



 row    name qty.x            description.x price.x qty.y              description.y price.y      change
1   1   alpha     2 number of alpha to order      20     3   number of alpha to order      20         qty
2   2    beta     3  number of beta to order      30     3      number of beta pieces      30        name
3   4 epsilon    NA                     <NA>      NA     1 number of epsilon to order      10       added
4   5   gamma     1 number of gamma to order      10     1   number of gamma to order      40 description
```

Comment: I believe this only works for equally sized dataframes, and there may be some rows where a new row was added, not modified from the first csv. I have added this case to my original post for clarity! Thank you!

Comment: Does that mean a row can also be deleted?

Comment: yes, a row that is in csv 1 may simply no longer exist in csv 2

Comment: @pbthehuman Also does that mean that the names are uniquely defined for each row? ie `alpha` is in row 1 and cannot be in any other row??

Comment: correct, if alpha is in row 1 it will not appear in any other row in csv1